# Fifa 12 PS3 controller configuration handout?

Tags: ps3, fifa-12

I am new to gaming and just got Fifa 12. But the "manual" is nonexistent.

Is there a pdf I can print that contains all default controller configurations for all the possible things a player can do? Like dribbling, special kicks and other stuff?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [this thread](http://forum.ea.com/uk/posts/list/1051984.page) john_wisdom shares a fan-made manual that seems to fit your needs. The current PS3 version can be found [here.](http://www.mediafire.com/?gggbh2m3em2wi9k)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there is an existing PDF for this already, but all the information you need to create one is in the game menu:

*Customize FIFA -> Settings -> Controls -> Button Help*

There you can find all commands for basic moves, skill moves and celebrations.

As you will see, the number of moves is quite large, so a PDF might not be exactly helpful. Learn the basic moves and keep experimenting. If you want to find out how a certain move works, look it up.

Fifa controls are mostly an experience thing, you will not be able to master all moves at once just because you have a big PDF of commands. ;)

Comment: But looking there every time is really frustrating because the menu is not very easy to navigate in. A pdf with the basic commands would be enough for me at my current learning stage :)